# funcion para deshabilitar el boton de regresar del navegador no funciona

Tags: javascript, html

estoy utilizando esta funcion

```
window.onload = function(){
    window.location.hash="no-back-button";
    window.location.hash="Again-No-back-button" //chrome
    window.onhashchange=function(){
        window.location.hash="no-back-button";
    }
}
```

y no funciona alguien que me diga por que, en html tengo algo asi

```
<html>
<body>

<script src="java/cambiar.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realmente no se puede desactivar la función de VOLVER en los navegadores. 
Muchos intentan sobrescribir comportamientos del navegador, pero es un tanto complejo. 
Lo mejor que puedes hacer es alertar al usuario del problema.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() { return "Todo su avance se perderá"; };
```

Esta pagina muestra muchos otros métodos en los que podrías deshabilitar el botón, pero ninguno es garantizado.
Además depende del navegador a utilizar.
-> https://www.irt.org/script/311.htm

PD* - Respuesta obtenida de SO en inglés -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381563/

Comment: muy bien muchisimas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: Si de verdad te sirve, marcala como respuesta para cerrar el tema ;)

Comment: pues es que realmente lo que yo queria era eso ver como desactivar ese boton en el navegador he visto documentacion de esta pagina incluso donde si funciona

Comment: Yo busque varias, muchas de ellas eran el mismo ejemplo usando .js, pero niguno lograba el resultado, luego encontré esa explicacion, y se fundamento con otras busquedas. Podrias seguir intentando, pero hasta el mas simple ejemplo, efectivamente, no funciono al deshabilitar el boton,

Comment: si yo igual he buscado muchas respuestas, pero todas son las mismas y veo en ejemplos que a veces si funcionan por eso estoy tratando de entender, pero cuando yo lo quiero hacer no funciona

Comment: Exacto, no funcionan, suerte de todos modos

Comment: gracias de todas formas por la ayuda :9